# How to make jquery mobile page responsive?

Tags: jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I have the following code snippet for a login home page. I want it to be responsive. how do I make it responsive using jQuery mobile?
Does jqm provide any default css for it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">

    <div data-role="content">
        <img src="./imgs/abc.jpg">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><img src="./imgs/home.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <form id="HLogin" method="POST">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="url">Username:*</label>
                        <input class="required" id="Lusername" name="uid_r" type="text" value="">          
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="url">Password:*</label>
                        <input id="Lpassword" name="pwd_r" type="password" value="">          
                    </div>              
                <button data-theme="b" type="submit">Login</button>       
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div> 
</body>
</html>  

custom.css:  

    .ui-block-a {
    width:70% !important;
}
.ui-block-b {
    width:30% !important;
}
```

Comment: Aren't they responsive ? Could you please elaborate ? Thanks!

Comment: @Smitha: Jquery mobile is already built in responsive design. see this link:1) http://www.slideshare.net/rockncoder/responsive-design-24339494 (2)http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652004/Responsive-Web-Design-with-jQuery-Mobile

Comment: I tried to change the screen resolution for the above page and it doesn't fit in. The login item overlaps on 70% block a. So just wanted to chcek what's going wrong.

Comment: Looks like you missed `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` tag in head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can add your css according screen and add min-width, which you want.

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
   .ui-block-a {
      width:0% !important;
   }
   .ui-block-b {
      width:100% !important;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 620px) {
   .ui-block-a {
     width:70% !important;
   }
   .ui-block-b {
      width:30% !important;
   }

}
```